# How to save an image in picture box after applying editing on it..These editing will show on picture when we open it in image viewer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, c#-3.0

i made a screen capturing application.. i applied drawing(simple lines) on it..
when i capture the screen and perform editing and save it..only the capture screen is save not the editing..i want to save all these editing on picture.. i m stuck here..
here is the code..

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    bool paint = false;
    SolidBrush color;
    private MessageBoxButtons buttonType;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
     this.Opacity = 0;
    time.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         SaveFileDialog savefiledialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    try
    {
        savefiledialog1.Title = "Save File";
        savefiledialog1.FileName = "Capture Screen";
        savefiledialog1.Filter = "JPEG |*.jpeg";
        if (savefiledialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            picture.Image.Save(savefiledialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        Application.Exit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}


    private void time_Tick_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    Rectangle bounds = default(Rectangle);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap screenshot = default(System.Drawing.Bitmap);
    Graphics graph = default(Graphics);
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    picture.Image = screenshot;
    time.Enabled = false;
    this.Opacity = 100;
    }

    private void picture_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = false;
    }

    private void picture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = true;
    }

    private void picture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paint)
        {
            Graphics g = picture.CreateGraphics();
            color = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            g.FillEllipse(color, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);
        }
    }      
}
```

}

Comment: Do you ever stop the timer, which overrides all previous modifications?

Comment: _Graphics g = picture.CreateGraphics();_ This is wrong and will not allow you to save the result. Instead you need to collect the data in the mousemove and draw it in the Paint event, using the e.Graphics obejct. Then you can use DrawToBitmap to dump it all into one bitmap you can save. OR: You can draw into the Image directly/destructively in the Mouse event using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pbox.image as Bitmap)